# treeinterpreter / feature selection with multidimensional data

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

In python i have been using treeinterpreter on 2d data. It has worked well and enabled me to look into the blackbox to understand what is going on. I am interested in the why than the predicted output.

However, a new set of data is given to me daily. It is the same categorised data every day but some of it is dynamic. This however has added a new dimension of time. It is not as important as the features / categories but still has an effect.

What is the best way of dealing with this so i can still look into the tree / svm / etc....i am not too fussed which one.

It may be i need to stack the models in order to get the insight - but i am unsure.

example of the data on one day below - the price change and rating can changes daily.

```
Wine      Country       Area        Grape        Class    Year    Price   Rating
A         France        Burgundy    Pinot Noir   Grand    2014    +6%      94
B         France        Burgundy    Chardonnay   1er      2014    -1%      91
C         France        Burgundy    Pinot Noir   1er      2014    +4%      96
D         USA           California  Pinot Noir            2013    +1%      92
E         USA           California  Blend                 2014    +0.5%    88
F         USA           California  Chardonnay            2014    -4%      81
G         USA           California  Chardonnay            2013    -5%      91
```